# Civilization A New Dawn: How may additional control tokens be placed when resolving the Civil Service focus card

Tags: civilization-a-new-dawn

I recently played Civilization A New Dawn for the first time, and during play the question arose as to how Control Tokens purchased using Trade Tokens on the Civil Service card should be allocated, as the card provides two methods of placement. The text on the Civil Service card reads the following:

> Place 2 control tokens on spaces matching this slot's terrain or lower that are adjacent to friendly cities.
>
> Then, place 1 control token on a space matching this slot's terrain or lower that is adjacent to a friendly space.

The `Trade Tokens` section under `Additional Rules` in the rule book does not specify any constraints on how the additional control tokens must be placed. The general rule in the `culture` section under `Focus Cards` does say the following:

> the player takes one of his or her unused control tokens and places it on a space adjacent to a friendly city

But it makes no mention of any exceptions existing to this rule, of which the Civil Service card is.

My gut feeling is that the additional tokens should be placed adjacent friendly cities, but I can see room for arguing more freedom in the placement of control tokens. Is there anything close to an official statement on how this should play out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ's got your back:

> **Civil Service:** Trade tokens spent with this card allow the player to place additional control tokens following the usual rules for placing control tokens, not the special rule for Civil Service’s secondary effect.

[image: FAQ rules]

**Source:** Official FAQ (as of 03-JUL-2018)